# Prove : $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a^2+c^2+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{a^2+c^2+1}{b^2+c^2+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^2+c^2+1}{a^2+b^2+1}}\geq 3$ with $a+b+c=1$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, karamata-inequality, majorization

### Claim :

> > Let $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$ and $a+b+c=1$ then we have :
> >
> > $$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a^2+c^2+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{a^2+c^2+1}{b^2+c^2+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^2+c^2+1}{a^2+b^2+1}}\geq 3$$

To prove it I try the Ji chen's theorem because we have :

$$\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a^2+c^2+1}+\frac{a^2+c^2+1}{b^2+c^2+1}+\frac{b^2+c^2+1}{a^2+b^2+1}\geq 3$$
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a^2+c^2+1}\frac{a^2+c^2+1}{b^2+c^2+1}+\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a^2+c^2+1}\frac{b^2+c^2+1}{a^2+b^2+1}+\frac{a^2+c^2+1}{b^2+c^2+1}\frac{b^2+c^2+1}{a^2+b^2+1}\geq 3$$
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a^2+c^2+1}\frac{a^2+c^2+1}{b^2+c^2+1}\frac{b^2+c^2+1}{a^2+b^2+1}=1$$

To prove the two first I use Karamata's inequality as we have .

> > Let $x,y,z,u,v,w>0$ such that $x\geq y \geq z$ and $u\geq v \geq w$ and :
> > $x\geq u$,
> > $xy\geq uv$,
> > $xyz\geq uvw$
> >
> > Then we have :
> > $$x+y+z\geq u+v+w$$

### Question :

Is there simpler ?

Thanks in advance !

Regards

Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:clearly this is of form $$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}\ge 3$$ which is true by am-gm

Comment: Well I don't expect it !That's nice ! I accept .

Comment: Hum I'm a little bit tired so It explain my lack of clear-sightedness (lol).

Comment: @ErikSatie thank you,sometimes the most simple answers doesn't strike  ,it happens to me too